# How to get 50 samples from each class of imagenet?

Tags: python, urllib, imagenet

I want to have for example 50 samples of each class in imagenet. I want to have access to URL of them.
I try to use this way to access to the samples of each class:
http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n01484850
but some URLs do not work. Do you know of any fast way that I can access 50 correct URLs for each class?
For each class, I save the .txt file of samples, and then use the code below to feed the samples to my deep CNN but because of some URLs that do not work, the code doesn't work.

Code:

```
f = open("C:\\Windows\\System32\\whiteshark.txt", "r")
number_of_lines = 50
for i in range(number_of_lines):
    line = f.readline()
    url, filename = (line, "3000.jpg")
    #print( urllib.URLopener().retrieve(url, filename))
    try:
        urllib.URLopener().retrieve(url, filename)
    except:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
    input_image = Image.open(filename)
    img_t = transform(input_image)
    batch_t = torch.unsqueeze(img_t, 0)
    print(url)
```

Comment: I added a missing `\` to the string which contains the filename.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to have more lines with urls in your text (say 1000), and keep trying to access each url, untill you reach 50 samples. Example:

```
acquired_samples = 0
while acquired_samples < 50:
    ....
    try:
        urllib.URLopener().retrieve(url, filename)
        acquired_samples += 1
    ...
```

You get the point.

*Disclaimer:* you might have to take a few precautions, so as not to fall into infinite loops.